# How do I get refresh token for Google Oauth 2.0 in my Angular Application?

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, refresh-token

I have already found a way to generate access token using ng-gapi, but is there a way in which I can get the refresh token, as the access token is only valid for one hour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you found the solution for this issue?
I have been stocked with a similar problem. According to [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications (Step 5)](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#exchange-authorization-code) article, we can get a refresh token from the response of the request to *https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token* endpoint with authorization code in parameters. This authorization code I got using **grantOfflineAccess()** method of GoogleAuth object, which returns a promise with this code. I'm not sure if this solution is correct enough, but it works fine for me. Here some methods, I hope it will help you too.

```js
private tokenRequestParams: TokenReqParams = {
    client_id: AuthService.CLIENT_ID_KEY,
    client_secret: AuthService.CLIENT_SECRET_KEY,
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200',
    grant_type: 'authorization_code'
  };

  /**
   * if a user was logged the method returns user info, if not - checks that if refresh token   has been stored
   * and accordingly to this uses different methods for user sing-in
   * @returns - the data of the authorized user
   */
  public login(): Observable<User> {
    const isUserLoggedIn = this.refreshToken && this.accessToken;
    if (isUserLoggedIn) {
      return this.getUserInfo();
    } else {
      return this.googleAuthService.getAuth().pipe(
        switchMap( auth => {
          return (!this.refreshToken) ? this.firstSignIn(auth) : this.signIn(auth);
        })
      );
    }
  }
  
  
    /**
   * The method makes sign-in action and return's data of the user who was authorized
   * method will be used when grants were allowed after first sign in
   * @params auth - GoogleAuth object
   * @returns - user data
   */
  private firstSignIn(auth: GoogleAuth): Observable<User> {
    return from(auth.grantOfflineAccess()).pipe(
      switchMap(code => this.fetchToken({code: code.code}).pipe(
        map(() => this.signInSuccessHandler(auth.currentUser.get()))
      ))
    );
  }
  
  
    /**
   * The method makes sign-in action and return's data of the user who was authorized
   * method will be used when grants were allowed after first sign in
   * @params auth - GoogleAuth object
   * @returns - user data
   */
  private signIn(auth: GoogleAuth): Observable<User> {
    return from(
      auth.signIn().then(
        (res: GoogleUser) => this.signInSuccessHandler(res),
        err => { throw Error(err); }
      )).pipe(
      map((user: User) => user),
      catchError(() => throwError('login failed'))
    );
  }


  /**
   * The method fetches access token or both tokens (access and refresh) depending of received options
   * and stores them to local and session storage's
   * @params params - object, that determine which grant of token gets
   * details: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#creatingclient
   * @returns - object with token data
   */
  private fetchToken(params: TokenAccessParams | TokenRefreshParams): Observable<Token> {
    const requestParams = {
      ...this.tokenRequestParams,
      ...params
    };
    return this.httpClient.post(this.TOKEN_ENDPOINT, requestParams).pipe(
      tap((res: Token) => {
        const {access_token, refresh_token} = res;
        sessionStorage.setItem(AuthService.SESSION_ST_ACCESS_TOKEN, access_token);
        if (refresh_token) { localStorage.setItem(AuthService.LOCAL_ST_REFRESH_TOKEN, refresh_token); }
      })
    );
  }


  /**
   * Method use current token to get new token
   * @returns - New token
   */
  private updateAccessToken(): Observable<any> {
    return this.fetchToken({
      refresh_token: this.refreshToken,
      grant_type: 'refresh_token'
    });
  }
```